# SQLAlchemy does not automatically populate foreign key field when a relationship is used

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a simple one-to-many relationship. I have `Project` and `Device` classes. A `Project` can have multiple `Device`s.

The program does not behave as I expect when I add a device to a project using the relationship.

The complete program is here:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()


class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Projects"

    name = Column('Name', String(50), primary_key=True)
    devices = relationship("Device", back_populates="project")


class Device(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Devices"

    serial_no = Column('SerialNo', String(50), primary_key=True)
    project_name = Column('ProjectName', String(50), ForeignKey("Projects.Name"))
    project = relationship("Project", back_populates="devices", foreign_keys=[project_name])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Project(name="MyProject")
    d = Device()

    print("Before adding device:")
    print(f"p.devices: {p.devices}")
    print(f"d.project: {d.project}")
    print(f"d.project_name: {d.project_name}")

    p.devices.append(d)

    print("After adding device:")
    print(f"p.devices: {p.devices}")
    print(f"d.project: {d.project}")
    print(f"d.project_name: {d.project_name}")
```

And here is the output:

```
Before adding device:
p.devices: []
d.project: None
d.project_name: None
After adding device:
p.devices: [<__main__.Device object at 0x000001FF049B22B0>]
d.project: <__main__.Project object at 0x000001FF03DB0D30>
d.project_name: None
```

All outputs are as expected except the last one `d.project_name`. `d.project_name` still returns `None`. I expect this to be populated as `MyProject` as well since `d.project` returns that project object.

What am I missing?

Comment: I recommend you spend a little time going through the Engine configuration and `Session` management sections of the [ORM Tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html). The `Session` is the thing that synchronizes your objects with the database, and you aren't using it in your example here. You add your objects to a `Session` and foreign keys are populated once any pending changes to the objects are "flushed" to the database, using either `Session.flush()` or `Session.commit()`.

Comment: @SuperShoot I did go through ORM Tutorial, but it was not clear to me that I needed a Session for this relationship to work. I am aware that my changes would not be reflected to the database I am using but I thought the objects would reflect the changes even if I haven't committed to the database.

Comment: Most of the time, primary keys are auto-increment and so the parent object needs to first be inserted into the database in order to get the primary key value assigned to it before the foreign key can be updated on any children.

Comment: So you'll need to establish an engine which can be as easy as `engine = create_engine("sqlite:///")` for an in-memory database, and a Session class, `Session = session_maker(bind=engine)`. Then create an instance of your  session, `s = Session()`, add your parent object to it, `s.add(p)`, and then `s.commit()` after `p.devices.append(d)`. Then access `d.project_name` and you will find it is populated on the child object.

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome .I hope you don't feel like I'm trying to be dismissive by directing you to the documentation, it is just that the tutorial does a very good job of explaining these foundation topics and you probably would't get anything out of an answer on here that you wouldn't get out of following along with that tutorial. Good luck with it all!

Comment: No problem. SQLAlchemy is a pretty big project with a lot of documentation (which is nice). I went through the tutorials as much as possible but there are probably parts where I didn't completely get/misunderstood the concept, I guess this was one of those.